# ¿Cómo saber que barra separadora se usa en el SO en que se ejecuta la aplicación?

Tags: java

¿Cómo se que barra de separación, Unix o Windows, usar en las rutas de un programa Java?
¿Necesito comprobar el SO en el que se esta ejecutando? Es decir, ¿la ruta relativa dentro del JAR adopta esta forma "res/strings/" o ésta otra "res\strings\" según el SO en el que se ejecute?
Si es así, esto me obliga a conocer el sistema o bien obtener una ruta absoluta y comprobar si se encuentra uno u otro separador para componer la ruta que va a funcionar en cada momento, ¿como se gestiona? ¿Hay una forma directa de saber que tipo de ruta va a funcionar?

Answer (score 2):

La clase `java.io.File` contiene cuatro variables de separador estático.

1. **`separator`**: Un String del separador dependiendo de la plataforma. Para Windows, es `\` y para Unix es `/`
2. **`separatorChar`**: Igual que `separator` pero nos da un Char
3. **`pathSeparator`**: Variable dependiente de la plataforma para separadores de ruta. Por ejemplo `PATH` o `CLASSPATH` Para Unix es `:` y para Windows es `;` .
4. **`pathSeparatorChar`**: Igual que `pathSeparator` pero del tipo char

Hay que tener en cuenta que todas ellas son variables finales y dependen del sistema.

Este código las muestra funcionando:

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/ZSDA27928)**

```
import java.io.File;


class Rextester
{  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("File.separator = "+File.separator);
        System.out.println("File.separatorChar = "+File.separatorChar);
        System.out.println("File.pathSeparator = "+File.pathSeparator);
        System.out.println("File.pathSeparatorChar = "+File.pathSeparatorChar);
    }

}
```

**Resultado (Unix)**

```
File.separator = /
File.separatorChar = /
File.pathSeparator = :
File.pathSeparatorChar = :
```

**Resultado (Windows)**

```
File.separator = \
File.separatorChar = \
File.pathSeparator = ;
File.pathSeparatorChar = ;
```

### Nota importante

> Podemos construir nuestras rutas de forma que sean totalmente
>   **independientes del sistema**, veamos una comparación:

```
//Una ruta hardcoded, no encontrará nuestro archivo en Unix
File archivoDependiente = new File("docs/mitexto.txt");

//Una ruta independiente del sistema
File archivoIndependiente = new File("docs"+File.separator+"mitexto.txt");
```

---

También se pueden construir las rutas independientes de la plataforma usando `System.getProperty()`.

Ejemplo:

```
class Rextester
{  
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String home = System.getProperty("user.home");
        String dir = System.getProperty("user.home") + System.getProperty("file.separator")
                + "MiProyecto" + System.getProperty("file.separator") + "Docs";
        System.out.println("home: " + home);
        System.out.println("dir: " + dir);

    }
}
```

**Resultado (Unix)**

```
home: /var/www
dir: /var/www/MiProyecto/Docs
```

Comment: ¿Para construir rutas Windows será necesario poner las barras separadoras dobles? p.e. "res\\strings\\"

Comment: @Orici No. Como muestra el código la idea es que Java lo haga solo, tomando el carácter separador del sistema en el que se ejecuta el programa. Si colocas doble barra para Windows fallará en Unix.

Comment: quería decir que al componer una ruta para Win, como la barra se usa como carácter de escape, sería necesario incluirla dos veces, comprobando antes si se usa la barra de un sistema u otro, p.e. yo tengo las rutas compuestas ya para Unix, y voy a usar la siguiente función:
/**
 * Changes the bars of the path, if the OS is Windows 
 *
 * *param     path   The path with bars for unix
 * *return     The path with bars for the OS
 */

private String preparePath( String path ) {

    
return ( File.separator.equals( "/" ))
      ? path
      : path.replaceAll( "/", "\\" );

}

Comment: Si construyes las rutas como dice en el apartado **Nota importante** no necesitas tener ninguna función que determine el Sistema Operativo y las convierta, sino que el mismo programa determina mediante `File.separator`  la ruta adecuada según el sistema. Lo que sería mejor es tener un método que te construya las rutas, usando una de las dos opciones indicadas en **Nota importante**